# Как получить данные из select в массив?

Tags: php, yii2, select

Я вывожу данные из бд в select следующим образом

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
     <h4>Вопросы входящие в эту тему</h4>
     <input id="search-assigned"><br>
     <?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $RightItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'id' => 'second']) ?>
</div>
```

При просмотре кода страницы получается следующее:

```
<select id="second" name="SQuizTopic[ID_REC][]" multiple="" size="20" style="width: 100%">
     <option value="457">17</option>
     <option value="458">18</option>
     <option value="459">19</option>
     <option value="441">1</option>
     <option value="447">7</option>
     <option value="449">9</option>
     <option value="450">10</option>
     <option value="451">11</option>
     <option value="453">13</option>
     <option value="454">14</option>
     <option value="461">21</option>
</select>
```

После вывода в select я редактирую данные, могу удалить либо добавить новые. Как мне сделать так, что бы после нажатия на кнопку "Конец редактирования" которая есть у меня на странице, все что осталось в данном селекте сохранилось в массив? В идеале хотелось бы получить 2 массива, в первом хранились бы value селектов, во втором хранились бы значения селектов. Я не представляю как сделать считывание данных с этого селекта по нажатию на клавишу. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: без javascript никак

Comment: @perfect можете привести небольшой пример?

Comment: читайте что такое ajax. если знаете jquery то вам поможет это http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку собираете все значения из select, например использую jQuery:

```
var array = [];
$('#second option').each(function() {
    array[ $(this).val()] = $(this).text();
});
```

Что делать с этими значениями - уже вам решать. Либо вставлять в форму каждое значение в виде `<input type="hidden" name="selectValue[]">` перед отправкой на сервер. Либо если используете ajax, передавать все значения на сервер, например как:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/save",
    type: "POST",
    data: {myArray : array}
});
```

На сервере смотреть:

```
$array = $_POST['myArray'];
```

Comment: Окей, логику примерно понял. Буду пытаться что либо сделать с этим